# Tkinter: How to adjust dates along x axis?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, tkinter, pandas

I have been tinkering with a function which accepts a DataFrame (which has an index of datetimes), then selects a column and turn it into a series, and then plots it. Everything seems fine but I cannot get the dates to display correctly. I would like the x-axis to tick by weeks and not by datapoint.

[image: Here is the output I am getting.]

```
    class App: 
        def __init__(self,master, df): 
            frame = Frame(master) 
            frame.pack() 


            series = df['Daily  T'].cumsum()

            self.f = Figure(figsize=(12,6), dpi=100, linewidth=2) 
            self.a = self.f.add_subplot(111) 
            self.a.grid(True) 
            self.a.set_xlabel("DATES")
            self.a.plot(series, 'r-o') 

            self.a.set_xticks(range(len(series)))

            self.a.set_xticklabels([datetime.strftime(date, '%x') for date in series.index])

            self.f.autofmt_xdate()


            self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=child_win_plot) 
            self.canvas.show() 
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1) 





    app=App(child_win_plot, filtered_df)
```

I am not sure what should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it but how about this

```
# range(0,len(series),7) give (0,7,14,21)
self.a.set_xticks(range(0,len(series),7))
```

and dates with empty string

```
# empty string in place of some dates 
# [date, '', '', '', '' , '', '', '' , date ...]
xlabels = [ datetime.strftime(date, '%x') if index%7 == 0 else '' for index, date in enumerate(series.index)]
self.a.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
```

or only dates - without empty strings

```
xlabels = [ datetime.strftime(date, '%x') for index, date in enumerate(series.index) if index%7 == 0 ]
self.a.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
```

Comment: The first solution did not work, the second solution did work. Also, enumerate is spelled slightly incorrectly. Other than that, it worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: `enumarate` :) You are right. I wrote code directly here - I have no matplotlib to test it.